# Phpmyadmin 5.1.0.RC1 & 5.0.4 error (Warning in ./libraries/classes/Config.php#1285 mkdir(): Permission denied)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, permission-denied, mkdir, php-8

I test phpmyadmin 5.0.4 and 5.1.0.RC1 on ubuntu server 20.04, and I'm geeting the following error :

```
Warning in ./libraries/classes/Config.php#1285
 mkdir(): Permission denied
Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Config.php#1285: mkdir(
string '/usr/share/phpmyadmin//var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig',
integer 504,
boolean true,
)
./libraries/classes/Template.php#57: PhpMyAdmin\Config->getTempDir(string 'twig')
./libraries/classes/Theme.php#101: PhpMyAdmin\Template->__construct()
./libraries/classes/Theme.php#174: PhpMyAdmin\Theme->__construct()
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#307: PhpMyAdmin\Theme::load(
string './themes/pmahomme',
string '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/./themes/pmahomme/',
)
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#79: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->loadThemes()
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#121: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->__construct()
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#385: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::getInstance()
./libraries/common.inc.php#232: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::initializeTheme()
./index.php#15: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

I've try to change owner of my ./libraries/classes/Config.php and /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig (created this folder "twig" too) by www-data (original "root"), but error wasn't resolved.

my vendor config is :

```
<?php
/**
 * File for vendor customization, you can change here paths or some behaviour,
 * which vendors such as Linux distributions might want to change.
 *
 * For changing this file you should know what you are doing. For this reason
 * options here are not part of normal configuration.
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

// phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
if (! defined('PHPMYADMIN')) {
    exit;
}
// phpcs:enable

/**
 * Path to vendor autoload file. Useful when you want to
 * have have vendor dependencies somewhere else.
 */
define('AUTOLOAD_FILE', ROOT_PATH . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php');

/**
 * Directory where cache files are stored.
 */
define('TEMP_DIR', ROOT_PATH . '/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * Path to changelog file, can be gzip compressed. Useful when you want to
 * have documentation somewhere else, eg. /usr/share/doc.
 */
define('CHANGELOG_FILE', ROOT_PATH . 'ChangeLog');

/**
 * Path to license file. Useful when you want to have documentation somewhere
 * else, eg. /usr/share/doc.
 */
define('LICENSE_FILE', ROOT_PATH . 'LICENSE');

/**
 * Directory where SQL scripts to create/upgrade configuration storage reside.
 */
define('SQL_DIR', ROOT_PATH . 'sql' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * Directory where configuration files are stored.
 * It is not used directly in code, just a convenient
 * define used further in this file.
 */
define('CONFIG_DIR', '/etc/phpmyadmin/');

/**
 * Filename of a configuration file.
 */
define('CONFIG_FILE', CONFIG_DIR . 'config.inc.php');

/**
 * Filename of custom header file.
 */
define('CUSTOM_HEADER_FILE', CONFIG_DIR . 'config.header.inc.php');

/**
 * Filename of custom footer file.
 */
define('CUSTOM_FOOTER_FILE', CONFIG_DIR . 'config.footer.inc.php');

/**
 * Default value for check for version upgrades.
 */
define('VERSION_CHECK_DEFAULT', true);

/**
 * Path to files with compiled locales (*.mo)
 */
define('LOCALE_PATH', ROOT_PATH . 'locale' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * Define the cache directory for routing cache an other cache files
 */
define('CACHE_DIR', ROOT_PATH . 'libraries' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

and i work with php8.0.

Thx for your backs !

Comment: Look at the path name in the error message carefully. Do you actually have a directory `'/usr/share/phpmyadmin//var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig'`?

Answer (score 14):

Enable template caching. Edit `/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` to add the line:

```
$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp/phpmyadmin';
```

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PhpMyAdmin#Enabling_template_caching

Comment: /tmp might not be writable: This line should work all the time: $cfg['TempDir'] = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpmyadmin';

Answer (score 5):

This is an addendum to Saurabh's answer. I had to manually create the temporary directory structure, and add an additional directory titled "twig". So you may need to create:

```
/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig
```

After following their instructions and creating the temp dirs then everything worked fine.

Comment: I had the same issue and all I did was create a new tmp directory

Answer (score 4):

Had same issue. Solved it by:

1. Open `vendor_config.php`:

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/vendor_config.php
   ```
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and search for **TEMP_DIR**
3. Change line to:

   ```
   define('TEMP_DIR', '/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/');
   ```
4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and search for **CONFIG_DIR**
5. Change line to:

   ```
   define('CONFIG_DIR', '/etc/phpmyadmin/');
   ```
6. Save file and exit. (Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. Press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)
7. Select the installed version: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/
8. Extract and replace the `/libraries/classes/Config.php` file with existing one.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Hi, thx for you answer but if you read my post, it's already done ;) and nothing change.

Comment: @NansLOIGNE According to your question, `TEMP_DIR` is defined as `ROOT_PATH . '/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` not just `'/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/'`

Answer (score 0):

In case this is not solved, it's most likely because apache user is not the default `www-data`.

When you install `phpmyadmin`, `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp` is owned by `www-data` by default.
Thus, if you changed apache default user, it can't write in this dir.

Fix is rather easy :

```
chown -R "apache-user:apache-group" /var/lib/phpmyadmin/*
chmod -R g+s /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VestaCP then you need to check the permission of phpMyAdmin in `/home/admin/`.

If the permission is in root, change it to the user permission and it will be resolved. Command:

```
chown -R admin:admin phpmyadmin
```