# Warning in ./libraries/classes/Config.php#1681 mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I just updated php and phpmyamdin and got these errors.

```
Warning in ./libraries/classes/Config.php#1681
 mkdir(): Permission denied

Backtrace

Config.php#1681: mkdir(
string '/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/tmp/twig',
integer 504,
boolean true,
)
Template.php#60: PhpMyAdmin\Config->getTempDir(string 'twig')
Theme.php#103: PhpMyAdmin\Template->__construct()
Theme.php#174: PhpMyAdmin\Theme->__construct()
ThemeManager.php#306: PhpMyAdmin\Theme::load(
string './themes/metro',
string '/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/./themes/metro/',
)
ThemeManager.php#89: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->loadThemes()
ThemeManager.php#129: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->__construct()
ThemeManager.php#397: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::getInstance()
common.inc.php#315: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::initializeTheme()
index.php#23: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

Warning in ./libraries/classes/Config.php#1681
 mkdir(): Permission denied

Backtrace

Config.php#1681: mkdir(
string '/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/tmp/twig',
integer 504,
boolean true,
)
HomeController.php#479: PhpMyAdmin\Config->getTempDir(string 'twig')
HomeController.php#254: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\HomeController->checkRequirements()
index.php#119: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\HomeController->index()

The $cfg['TempDir'] (/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this.

Warning in ./libraries/classes/Config.php#1681
 mkdir(): Permission denied

Backtrace

Config.php#1681: mkdir(
string '/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/tmp/twig',
integer 504,
boolean true,
)
Template.php#60: PhpMyAdmin\Config->getTempDir(string 'twig')
Theme.php#103: PhpMyAdmin\Template->__construct()
Theme.php#174: PhpMyAdmin\Theme->__construct()
ThemeManager.php#306: PhpMyAdmin\Theme::load(
string './themes/metro',
string '/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/./themes/metro/',
)
ThemeManager.php#89: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->loadThemes()
ThemeManager.php#129: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->__construct()
ThemeManager.php#397: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::getInstance()
common.inc.php#315: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::initializeTheme()
version_check.php#20: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

I've tried making the directory and it didn't work and changing the permissions to 777 is a terrible fix and I don't wanna do that. Also I am on linux Manjaro gnome

Fix it with this simple fix.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66016297/11251368

Also how do I tag as anwsered?

Comment: Then chmod to 0774

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: Well then you need to figure out what the group/owner of the map is and as which user your process is running

Comment: The group is root and all other folder that phpmyadmin access with no problem is root group aswell.

Comment: The group definitely shoudln't be root then

Answer (score 4):

I made this directory: `/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/tmp/twig`
and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by giving permission **777 (rwx)** to **tmp** directory :

1. go to tmp :

> cd  /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp

or as you have here:

> cd  /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/tmp

2. and do this :

> sudo chmod 777 .

Comment: Be careful with that. You are giving every user all access rights to that directory. More generally, make sure the user executing PHP (usually www-data) has access to the tmp folder. You can achieve that for example by letting www-data own that directory: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data tmp`